# How to make reg exp find "h" in start of line and "o" in the end of line

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
message = 'hello' # Text
print(re.search("^ho$", message)) # None
```

How to make reg exp find "h" in start of line and "o" in the end of line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
re.search("^h.*o$", message)
```

The dot `.` is a special sign, that matches every character.
The asterisk `*` is a special sign, too, that matches as many elements of the group before.

In the combination this matches all signs between `o` and `h`.

Here you can find a list with [the special characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for regular expressions.

Comment: Might be helpful to clarify that `.*` will match any number of any type of character between the "h" and "o"

Comment: @KellyBundy Pretty sure that was a typo, but the lack of a `$` definitely does change what the expression matches.

Comment: [Asterix](https://www.google.com/search?q=asterix&oq=aste&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j0i67j46i67l2j0i67l2j46i67j0i10i67.2702j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Sorry, that is a stupid typo. [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

Change the "^ho$" to "^h.*o$".  The ".*" will match any number of any type of character between the "h" and "o".